# Passing custom fields along with standard to lambda from API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I know there are multiple docs out there which will explain how to pass custom fields from API gateway to lambda function but my requirement is a bit different.

I have a lambda function which accepts the standard field values passed to it and that works perfectly. Recently I created a function which accepts a key value called `instance` and value as `valueofinstance` and this data is fetched in lambda like this `-> ec2_val = event["instance"]`.

The problem I'm facing right now is that the user invoking the API can only pass the "instance" data from request body and the lambda function is not designed to catch the data from body, and the changes are frozen in lambda so I cannot just go and make changes to it whereas I'm free to develop on the API Gateway side.

The event which is acceptable should look something like this

```json
{
 "path": "some data"
 "httpMethod": "POST",
 "queryStringParameters": {"type":"ec2"},
 "requestContext": {},
 "pathParameters": {},
 "all other standard fields"...

 "instance": "I-abcdas133"
}
```

Other standard fields are also required because those values are fetched in the lambda like this

```
name = event["pathParameters"].get("name", "").upper()
action = event["pathParameters"].get("action", "").upper()
request_id = event.get("requestContext", {}).get("requestId", {})
```